# What is happening here in lubridate::unique.Interval?

Tags: r, lubridate

Sample data adapted from here: https://www.reddit.com/r/rstats/comments/4j2efe/help_counting_unique_days_in_r_with_overlap_and/

```
df = read.table(text = "Start            End
           1/8/2015         1/9/2015
           1/8/2015         1/9/2015
           1/13/2015        1/15/2015
           1/7/2015         1/17/2015
           1/12/2015        1/22/2015
           1/8/2015         1/16/2015" , header = T)
```

Create interval

```
df %>% transmute(Start = mdy(Start), End = mdy(End), Interval = interval(Start, End)) 

       Start        End                       Interval
1 2015-01-08 2015-01-09 2015-01-08 UTC--2015-01-09 UTC
2 2015-01-08 2015-01-09 2015-01-08 UTC--2015-01-09 UTC
3 2015-01-13 2015-01-15 2015-01-13 UTC--2015-01-15 UTC
4 2015-01-07 2015-01-17 2015-01-07 UTC--2015-01-17 UTC
5 2015-01-12 2015-01-22 2015-01-12 UTC--2015-01-22 UTC
6 2015-01-08 2015-01-16 2015-01-08 UTC--2015-01-16 UTC
```

Find unique interval. What happened to this interval? 2015-01-12 UTC--2015-01-22 UTC is gone. Is this intended behavior?

```
.Last.value %>% select(Interval) %>% unique

                        Interval
1 2015-01-08 UTC--2015-01-09 UTC
3 2015-01-13 UTC--2015-01-15 UTC
4 2015-01-07 UTC--2015-01-17 UTC
6 2015-01-08 UTC--2015-01-16 UTC
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

2015-01-12 UTC--2015-01-22 UTC is removed because it is a duplicated case for 2015-01-07 UTC--2015-01-17 UTC, even though they are not identical objects but they are equal to each other under `==` operator.

```
> intervalDf
       Start        End                       Interval
1 2015-01-08 2015-01-09 2015-01-08 UTC--2015-01-09 UTC
2 2015-01-08 2015-01-09 2015-01-08 UTC--2015-01-09 UTC
3 2015-01-13 2015-01-15 2015-01-13 UTC--2015-01-15 UTC
4 2015-01-07 2015-01-17 2015-01-07 UTC--2015-01-17 UTC
5 2015-01-12 2015-01-22 2015-01-12 UTC--2015-01-22 UTC
6 2015-01-08 2015-01-16 2015-01-08 UTC--2015-01-16 UTC
> intervalDf[4,3]
[1] 2015-01-07 UTC--2015-01-17 UTC

> intervalDf[5,3]
[1] 2015-01-12 UTC--2015-01-22 UTC
> intervalDf[4,3] == intervalDf[5,3]
[1] TRUE
```

However

```
> identical(intervalDf[4,3], intervalDf[5,3])
[1] FALSE
```

This possibly also implies that `unique` uses the `==` as the comparison function. If you want to keep them, you may convert the `Interval` column to character then apply the unique function.

**Update**:
Inconsistency of `unique` function on single and multiple columns data frame.

```
> dfTest
  x                       Interval
1 1 2015-01-08 UTC--2015-01-09 UTC
2 1 2015-01-08 UTC--2015-01-09 UTC
3 1 2015-01-13 UTC--2015-01-15 UTC
4 1 2015-01-07 UTC--2015-01-17 UTC
5 1 2015-01-12 UTC--2015-01-22 UTC
6 1 2015-01-08 UTC--2015-01-16 UTC
> unique(dfTest)
  x                       Interval
1 1 2015-01-08 UTC--2015-01-09 UTC
3 1 2015-01-13 UTC--2015-01-15 UTC
4 1 2015-01-07 UTC--2015-01-17 UTC
5 1 2015-01-12 UTC--2015-01-22 UTC
6 1 2015-01-08 UTC--2015-01-16 UTC
> dfTest1
                        Interval
1 2015-01-08 UTC--2015-01-09 UTC
2 2015-01-08 UTC--2015-01-09 UTC
3 2015-01-13 UTC--2015-01-15 UTC
4 2015-01-07 UTC--2015-01-17 UTC
5 2015-01-12 UTC--2015-01-22 UTC
6 2015-01-08 UTC--2015-01-16 UTC
> unique(dfTest1)
                        Interval
1 2015-01-08 UTC--2015-01-09 UTC
3 2015-01-13 UTC--2015-01-15 UTC
4 2015-01-07 UTC--2015-01-17 UTC
6 2015-01-08 UTC--2015-01-16 UTC
```

Two methods definition that explains the difference.

```
> getAnywhere("unique.data.frame") A single object matching ‘unique.data.frame’ was found It was found in the following places   package:base   registered S3 method for unique from namespace base   namespace:base with value

function (x, incomparables = FALSE, fromLast = FALSE, ...)  {
    if (!identical(incomparables, FALSE)) 
        .NotYetUsed("incomparables != FALSE")
    x[!duplicated(x, fromLast = fromLast, ...), , drop = FALSE] } <bytecode: 0x10c2ab0a0> <environment: namespace:base>
> getAnywhere("duplicated.data.frame") A single object matching ‘duplicated.data.frame’ was found It was found in the following places package:base   registered S3 method for duplicated from namespace base namespace:base with value

function (x, incomparables = FALSE, fromLast = FALSE, ...)  {
    if (!identical(incomparables, FALSE)) 
        .NotYetUsed("incomparables != FALSE")
    if (length(x) != 1L) 
        duplicated(do.call("paste", c(x, sep = "\r")), fromLast = fromLast)
    else duplicated(x[[1L]], fromLast = fromLast, ...) } <bytecode: 0x10c33a4b0> <environment: namespace:base>
```

Comment: So `getAnywhere("unique.Interval")` indicates that the `@.Data` and `@start` of the intervals are stored in a data.frame. Then the function relies on `unique.data.frame`. `@.Data` seems to be the `time_length` of the interval. Do you know how I can get the source to `getAnywhere("==.Interval")`? I may have to create an issue on github to see if this is intended behavior.

Comment: Following your lead, I think the reason lies in the fact that the `unique` function is defined differently for single and multiple columns data frame. I added more tests in the answer, hopefully it will help to find the answer.

Comment: Ok I figured it out. `class(dfTest1 %>% select(Interval))` is `data.frame`. `unique.data.frame` is the issue. `unique.Interval` works as intended. As a test case. `unique(unique(new("Interval"
                  , .Data = c(864000, 864000)
                  , start = structure(c(1420588800, 1421020800), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"
                  ), tzone = "UTC")
                  , tzone = "UTC")))` works as intended.

Comment: Yep, That's the answer.